# Meteor packages decoupled

Tags: meteor, package

Two part question.

1- I managed to create a package with meteor but I had to explicitly assign to the output, now if the package is not available I'll get an error.
How to check if the package is available or enabled and if so use it in code or template.

2- let's say I have 2 packages, projects and tasks, each of them can work separately from the other.
I want  to create a projects if project package is available.
I want  to create a tasks if task package is available.
I want to assign tasks to projects if these both packages are available.
How to achieve such flexibility with decoupled packages with meteor.

Comment: (1) What does "but I had to explicitly assign to the output" mean? (2) "I want to create a tasks if task package is available" - from within an app or from within a package?

Comment: 1- I meant I added directly assuming the package is available.
2- Packages can be enable it and disabled from an admin, therefor I need a way to handle that.

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `Package` object (on the global scope) list all the installed packages for an application.

You could test the presence of one of your package by doing something like this:

```
//will return an Object if package is loaded or undefined
if(Package['package:name']) {
  //...
}
```